# Can I power my microcontroller system directly from a 3V lithium coincell (transient consideration)?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, transient

My device has to be powered with user replaceable 2032 coincell.
I have a ~3.3V microcontroller like nrf52832. Its datasheet says:
[image]

[image]

So lithium coincell voltage range (3.3V - 0V) is in operating conditions (microcontroller has brown out detector). I would like to power the microcontroller directly, straight from the battery.

But, is there a possibility that any ESD or hotplugging transients can occur during battery replacement, that could harm microcontroller?
Even if I add ESD suppresion diode across the battery contacts, there's not enough reserve in microcontroller VDD range?

There's a lithium ion battery in 2032 size on the market: [https://www.amazon.com/LIR2032-Rechargeable-Li-ion-Button-Battery/dp/B074CV44LC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074CV44LC)

Would you consider someone could try to power our circuits with this?

Comment: "Even if I add ESD suppresion diode across the battery contacts, there's not enough reserve in microcontroller VDD range?" What do you mean by that? An ESD diode will not reduce the supply voltage.

Comment: @Arsenal Sorry I was mistaken, thanks You guys for explaining it to me. Didn't realised one uses diffrent protective components for ESD suppresion and hotplugging. I generally meant that you won't find a varistor or TVS that has a clamping voltage of 3.9V, you have to choose one rated a bit higher and their clamping voltage could raise even higher than their rated DC voltage. That's my interpretation of: [link](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/design_guides/varistors/littelfuse_varistor_dc_application_varistor_design_guide.pdf.pdf)

Comment: A lot of cr2032 batteries are rated for only very low supply current, so making these user replaceable is risky. You may get users complaining that their replacement batteries cause the device to brown out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nominal voltage is perfectly in spec, as pointed out by Autistic.

On the other hand, ESD and hotplugging events are two different things.
An ESD event can expose the circuit to thousands of volts, with relatively little pulse energy.

But in a hotplugging event, you deal with well-known voltage, that can be out of range and has to be considered as a steady overvoltage (the duration of someone plugging something in can vary quite much and is much longer than a spark caused by ESD). One of the first things that will happen when someone hotswaps a device that is not designed for hotswapping is that the ESD protection diodes get fried ;)

But in my opinion, it is highly unlikely that you get problems with either of those effects:

- Hotplugging in general is only a problem when there is more than two contacts involved because the order, in which those make contact, is what matters. So there is no "*hot*plugging" when talking about inserting a coin cell. Just normal "plugging" of plus and minus.
- ESD should not be that much of an issue for supply terminals, which typically have a quite large capacity which can absorb charge pulses to some extend. Most microcontrollers have rudimentary ESD protection included. It's up to you to add this extra savety, but if it's some kind of low-cost and not safety critical device, I personally wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

It will be fine, Volts are not too high when the coin cell is fresh. Normally there are lots of bypass caps that would suck up any little spikes.